# CloudKit as a CMS using a regular web host, not sure where to begin? Is it possible?

Tags: ios, icloud, cloudkit, cloudkit-web-services

CloudKit JS looks interesting. Yes, I know all about Parse, but was wondering if we can build a simple CMS on my server that can use the new CloudKit JS features: Authenticate, Add, Delete, etc. Or can this only run as a CMS in an App environment (like on an iPad)? AKA, the Public Container?

Basically what I'm trying to do is have my clients populate the App with data using CloudKit JS (using a simple web form front end), and not have to resort to using a php/mysql setup?

Question: Can CloudKit function now as my CMS? Finding zero examples, LOVE to learn!

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloutKitWebServicesReference/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015240

> If you have a CloudKit app, you can use CloudKit web services to provide a web interface for users to access the same data as your app. You must have the schema for your databases already created to use CloudKit web services. CloudKit web services provides an HTTP interface to fetch, create, update, and delete records, zones, and subscriptions. You also have access to discoverable users and contacts

Comment: More info here:  From Apple:


Some database operations require the user to sign in using their Apple ID. Your web app will need to handle authentication errors and present the user with a dialog to sign in. Apple actually presents the sign in page through a redirect URL so that the user’s credentials remain confidential.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, this is exactly the type of functionality that the CloudKit Web Services are meant for. As long as you have an application published in either the Mac or iOS App Store you can have a web presence, for instance in the form of a CMS.

Is there a reason why you think this is not possible or somehow prohibited? There is nothing preventing you from doing this in the Terms and Conditions as far as I can tell.

The CloudKit catalog sample project is a great way to get started:
https://cdn.apple-cloudkit.com/cloudkit-catalog/

Comment: Yes, however documentation is pretty slim. And folks I'm talking to now are: OMG! It's un/secure, I'm hearing 13 opinions from 12 people. Ok, digging in now. I'm trying to do all in Swift, Apples one sample is ObjC, and zero other tutorials, examples, etc out there. Like Zero. Of course it's only 100 hours old. :-)

Comment: What do you mean when you say un/secure? Can you be more specific?The sample code (CloudKit Catalog) and JS reference documentation is there and should be enough to get started, no?

Answer (score 0):

Ok this a great talk at WWDC 2015, explain lots:  CloudKit JS and Web Services

CloudKit.js is the new library that provides web access to your app data stored in iCloud. Explore the new web service APIs and learn how to extend your iOS or OS X apps to the web using CloudKit.

https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=710